# Why in Array sizeof(A[0]) and sizeof(A+0) are different?

Tags: c++

I have started learning pointer in C++ and I solved a lot of problems with it but I can't solve this problem? Can anyone explain me this problem?

Here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int A[]= {1,2,3,4,5};
     cout<<"Size of A in main = "<<sizeof(A)<<endl;
     cout<<"Size of A[0] in main = "<<sizeof(A[0])<<endl;
     cout<<"Size of A+0 in main = "<<sizeof(A+0)<<endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Here is my problem - I get this output:

```
Size of A in main = 20
Size of A[0] in main = 4
Size of A+0 in main = 8
```

Comment: `a[0]` has type `int`, so it is 4 bytes, `a+0` has type `int*` ie pointer - it is 8 bytes

Comment: Please no images of code.

Comment: Don't show code and other text in images. Copy-paste into the question text instead. See [ask].

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to use `*(A + 0)` which is equivalent to `A[0]`?

Comment: Perhaps the more interesting question is why `sizeof(A)` and `sizeof(A + 0)` are different

Answer (score 0):

A[0] means element at a+0 . i.e., *(A+0) which is int in your case and the size of int is 4 bytes.    A+0 means pointer and its size is 8 bytes.